# Incorrect total number of frames being returned by cap.get(7) function of cv2 module

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to find out the total number of frames in a video . The video is 13 seconds long and has a fps of 25 . So theoretically , the number of frames present in the video should be 13 * 25 = 325 frames .

```
total_frames = cap.get(7)
print(total_frames)
```

This function however returns the number of frames as 326 . Where is the extra 1 frame coming form ?

Comment: 0,1,2,..9, 10 => 11 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reciprocal of frame rate (25) is .040.

Now consider a video that is 40msec long.
How many frames does it have, one?
No, a single-frame "video" would have duration zero.
Our very short video has two frames, with 40msec between them.

Your video goes on for a few seconds beyond that,
but the concept is still the same, you need to account for the initial frame.